# Why doesn't Pairing Axiom depend on Empty Set Axiom?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Definition.**  For any sets $u$ and $v$, the pair set $\{u, v\}$ is the set whose only members are $u$ and $v$.

Is this definition the direct result of Pairing Axiom? Or should it be first proved that any sets exist from Empty Set Axiom and Power Set Axiom?

When considering first assumption, in Pairing Axiom

> For any sets $u$ and $v$, there is a set having as members just $u$ and $v$.

I understand each axiom is independent of the other. Pairing Axiom assumes there exist sets(e.g. $u$ and $v$). It's not related to Empty Set Axiom(which shows set existence) by independency. But if it is possible to just say there exist sets, why do we need Empty Set Axiom? It seems that Pairing Axiom should be based on at least Empty Set Axiom to show $u$ and $v$ exist.

Comment: "Pairing Axiom assumes there exists sets"- no it doesn't. It's like me saying "any unicorn has a horn"- that doesn't necessarily mean there are unicorns. In other words, the pairing axiom says that *given* $u,v$, $\{u, v\}$ exists, but it doesn't say that there is $u, v$ in the first place.

Comment: @Vercingetorix I got it. It's very hard to throw away a prejudice which already exists in my head. I should try to empty all the things that I have when learning set theory. Thanks.

Comment: In some presentations, e.g, [1], instead of the Empty Set Axiom, we have Existence: $\exists x(x=x).$ The existence of $\emptyset$ follows from this and some of the other axioms. All the other axioms except Infinity begin with "$\forall$" so anything beginning "$\exists$" cannot be deduced from only them. REFERENCE. [1]. Kunen, K. Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs.